# How to smooth the crease created by mirror modifier

Tags: subdivision-surface, mirror

This is my first blender project and I don't know how to handle the crease in the middle created by the mirror modifier. I am using a subdivision surface modifier. I tried adjusting in edit mode but it just looks more and more like a football... But I want to smooth the face out.[image: piggy1]
[image: piggy2]

Comment: hello, maybe put your Mirror above the Subdivision Surface modifier

Comment: And if you already have done that, check if _Merge_ is enabled in the Mirror modifier.

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same issue myself;  In my case it was caused by a face existing in the middle of the model.
Deleting the internal face, with clipping and merge turned on in the mirror modifier removes this problem.